# How to get the CSS to correctly align the titles?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Currently when the code runs both my title fields appear above the same table. It also lower cases all letters except for the first one. I wanted to have a title above each table. The main code looks like,

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>
  <div id="field">
      <%= f.label "test" %>
      <%= f.text_field :test_title %><br>
  </div>    
  <div id="field">
      <%= f.label "Description" %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %><br>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <br><%= f.submit %><br>
  </div>    
  <div id="title">
      <%= f.label "Associated worlds" %><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="add_fields">
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Associate New world", f, :pwss_wbss %><br><br>
  </div>    
  <div id="fields">
      <% if @test.valid? %>
        <table id="sort_table" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Line Item</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% if @test.valid? %>
                  <%= f.fields_for :tests_worlds, @test.tests_worlds.each do |builder| %>
                    <%= render "tests_world_row", f: builder %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <% end %>
  </div>

  <div id="title">
      <%= f.label "States" %><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="add_fields">
    <% if @test.valid? %>
      <%= f.fields_for :state, @test.states.each do |builder| %>
        <%= render "states_fields", f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %><br>
  </div>

  <div id="add_fields">
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add State", f, :state %>
  </div>

  <div id="fields">
      <% if @state.valid? %>
        <table id="sort_table" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Line Item</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%= f.fields_for :states, @test.states.each do |builder| %>
                  <%= render "states_row", f: builder %>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The CSS code I am using for the title fields is:

```
div#title label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px,5px,0px,5px;
    min-width: 80px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: Blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div#title {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

When this runs, both titles appear on one line above both tables. How do I get the title so that each one appears above the respective table?

Here is an image of what it displays

[image]

Comment: Please post the resulting html.

Comment: If you could copy and paste the HTML and CSS into a JSfiddle it would be much easier to solve

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use title as a tag, set it as a class rather than an Id in the HTML. ID's should only appear once in any page.

Also, it may have something to do with the display being inline-block only on the titles. If the other elements aren't also `inline-block` they may render in a different order.

I tend to use `inline-block` for pretty much entire pages. Try setting the value of the container div or the body to `inline-block` and see if that helps.

Comment: I am already using display inline-block on the others as well.